# How to create a dialog the same open in app effect [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, dialog

I see this app has an interesting dialog UI. How to create it in Flutter?

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/RUcHKhW.mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body must be at least 30 characters. For more information, you can check this package: https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet